# Character degrees in induced blocks

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $U\leq H\leq G$ a chain of subgroups.

Presume that $p$ is a prime dividing the order of $U$.

Suppose that $b_1$ is a $p$-block of $U$ and $b_2$ a $p$-block which is conjugated to $b_1$ via an element $g\in G$. Assume that both $B_1:=b_1^H$ and $B_2:=b_2^H$ are defined in the sense of Brauer.

If the character degrees of $\text{Irr}(b_1)$ and of $\text{Irr}(B_1)$ are known, what can be derived about the character degrees of $\text{Irr}(B_2)$ ?

Comment: This is probably the case, but are you assuming that $g$ normalizes $H$?

Comment: @DavidCraven : If $g$ normalizes $H$, isn't it clearly the case that $B_{1}$ and $B_{2}$ have the same character degrees?

Comment: @GeoffRobinson That's what I thought. But if $g$ doesn't normalize $H$ surely you have very little control over the induced block?

Comment: @DavidCraven : I think so, which is why I hadn't attempted an answer

Comment: Alas, I cannot suppose that $g$ normalizes $H$.   :-(

Comment: I think it's not even going to be true in general that $B_2$ has the same number of characters as $B_1$. @GeoffRobinson do you agree?

Comment: @DavidCraven: I can see no reason why they should have the same number of characters.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much.